# How to write hoverHandler in JavaScript to change color of an element when hovering?

Tags: javascript, events, handler, web

```
function hoverHandler(e)
{
if(event.target.getAttribute("id") != "hovering")
{
    event.target.setAttribute("id", "hovering");
}
}
```

This is the code I have, I also have a CSS that sets the color when id is hovering.

The problem:
1) As I am hovering, the color does not get reset back to previous color when I leave the element

Comment: Do you need to use this function or any javascript solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding, and make sure your checking for `onmouseout` as well

```
 <script>
 function hoverHandler(e)
  {
 if(e.id=="red")    // hovering
 {
 e.id="blue"; 
 }else {
e.id="red"; 
 }
 }
 </script>
<span onmouseover="hoverHandler(this)" onmouseout="hoverHandler(this)">test</span>
```

or an inline event handlers could be

```
<style>#startStyle {color:lime} #red {color:red}#blue{color:blue}</style>


 <span onmouseover="this.id='red'" onmouseout="this.id=''">test</span>
```

`onmouseout` would default back to the base style if any; or

```
 <span onmouseover="this.id='red'" onmouseout="this.id='startStyle'">test</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use Css to solve the problem?

Something like

```
.element:hover
{
 background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

where element is the class name

Comment: Yeah but that is not allowed in my assignment I have to use handlers.